# how to fix this.validator is not a function

Tags: validation, express-validator, jsonresult

validationResult is not working well and returns typeError validatorResult is not a function but the problem still continues

ValidatorFields.js file:

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const validatorFields = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  next();
};

module.exports = validatorFields;
```

auth.js file:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const { check } = require("express-validator");
const routes = Router();
const { validEmail } = require("../helpers/validatorDB.js");
const validateFields = require("../helpers/ValidatorFields.js");
const AuthController = require("../controllers/authController.js");

routes.post(
  "/register",
  [
    check("name", "Name is required").not().isEmpty(),
    check("email", "Invalid email").isEmail(),
    check("password", "Password must have more than 8 characters").isLength({
      min: 8,
    }),
    check("email").custom(validEmail),
    validateFields,
  ],
  AuthController.register
);

routes.post(
  "/login",
  [
    check("email", "Invalid email").isEmail(),
    check("password", "Password is required").not().isEmpty(),
  ],
  AuthController.login
);

module.exports = routes;
```

return json data is:

```
errors": [
        {
            "type": "field",
            "value": "taner@gmail.com",
            "msg": "this.validator is not a function",
            "path": "email",
            "location": "body"
        }
]
```

I check for missing or incorrectly defined functions called this.validator but still the same problem persists.I updated your express-validator version but it doesn't work. If the error still persists, I used the current version of express-validator and it still didn't work.Am I wrong? Any help is much appreciated. "express-validator - req.this.validator is not a function is not a function"

json data is:

```
{
    "name":"tanertaner",
    "email": "taner@gmail.com",
    "password":"tanertaner"
}
```

result data:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "type": "field",
            "value": "taner@gmail.com",
            "msg": "this.validator is not a function",
            "path": "email",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```

and
check("name", "Name is required").not().isEmpty(),

TypeError: check is not a function
\routes\auth.js:11:5)
is a result check not null

But the login process is successful, I only get a registration error.